# How to forcibly reset a socket in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, reset

I'm receiving 'read ECONNRESET' errors from my Node.js application (might be client or server connections, I'm not sure).

As part of fixing these, I'd like to do some local testing, and preferably set up automated tests for it. I want to write a Node client & server that hard resets connections as soon as they're established, so that I can test this.

Setting up the server/client is easy, but I'm not sure how to forcibly reset the connection to reproduce the issue I'm seeing here. The Node [socket docs](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) don't mention resets anywhere

Any ideas?

Comment: With an open client connection, ungracefully kill the server

Comment: I don't think that works. Net servers only have a very gentle [close()](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback), which doesn't kill open connections, and fixes like [server-destroy](https://github.com/isaacs/server-destroy/blob/master/index.js) just call socket.destroy() on each socket, which appears to cleanly close them.

Comment: Looks like this might be possible by implementing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888429/how-to-make-a-hard-abortive-close-on-a-tcp-connection using https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket, but it's going to be very hard work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update 2023

The linked issue was merged. You can now send RST packages with `socket.resetAndDestroy()`.

```js
const net = require('net');

const socket = new net.Socket();

socket.connect(8000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
    socket.write(
        'GET / HTTP/1.1\n' +
        'Host: example.com\n\n'
    );
    setTimeout(() => socket.resetAndDestroy(), 0);
});
```

## Old Anwser

There's no perfect solution to this, as far as I can tell, but I've found two options for this, and [filed a bug against Node to add proper support](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27428).

For my problem (start an HTTP request, then RST the socket) I found two solutions:

## Destroy the socket just before receiving a packet

```js
const net = require('net');

const socket = new net.Socket();
socket.connect(8000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
    socket.write(
        'GET / HTTP/1.1\n' +
        'Host: example.com\n\n'
    );
    setTimeout(() => socket.destroy(), 0);
});
```

If you know you're about to receive a packet on this connection, you can `destroy()` the socket immediately beforehand. This does not send an RST, but will send an RST in response to future packets.

To do this, you need to race to destroy the socket after your message is written, but before the response arrives. For local connections especially this can be tricky - the `setTimeout(() => socket.destroy(), 0)` is the most reliable solution I've found, but YMMV, and it's certainly not guaranteed. I expected the `write()` callback to work more reliably, but it doesn't seem to.

## Use another language (i.e. Python)

For me, I've now fallen back to using Python for testing, since it has direct control for this. To send a RST packet in Python:

```py
import socket
import time
import struct

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 8000

# Connect to the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

# Start an HTTP request
s.send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\
Host: example.com\r\n\
\r\n")
time.sleep(0.1)

# RST the socket without reading the response
# See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6440364/68051 for context
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack('ii', 1, 0))
s.close()
```

Hopefully the Node team will take a look at adding similar support soon (see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27428), but the above may be helpful in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer but perhaps more direct:

```
const net = require('net');

const client = net.connect(8124, "localhost", () => {
  console.log('connected!');
  client.destroy(new Error('ECONNRESET'))
});
```

from [Simulate an ECONNRESET error on a Node.js net.Socket instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836424/simulate-an-econnreset-error-on-a-node-js-net-socket-instance)

Comment: Does this actually reset the socket, or just simulate it within node? There's use cases for that but it is different from a network perspective - i.e. the other end of the socket won't receive a RST packet.

Comment: @TimPerry Resets it if one first do a `write` on the socket. I.e. `socket.write('HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'); socket.destroy(Error('ECONNRESET'));` (Not widely tested)