# Auto restart node.js socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am now experimenting on node.js socket.io and trying to restart the socket.io server once it reach a specific number of connection. Below is my code so far but, really don't know how to execute the restart command.

```
var connectionsLimit = 100

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  if (io.engine.clientsCount > connectionsLimit) {
    socket.emit('restart', { message: 'server will restart' })

    return
  }

 io.on('restart', function(data) {

    //how to restart?
 });

})
```

Comment: this link might be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854514/how-to-forcibly-reset-a-socket-in-node-js

Comment: You want is reject all socket clients?