# How to know if server rebooted or crashed reliably on the client

Tags: sockets, tcp, segmentation-fault

I have a Server and Client which is using TCP for communication and file transfer. In the middle of the transfer of file from Server to Client, the server crashes or reboots. The client was doing a read of the connection FD while this was happening and it returned back 0 indicating EOF. This seems to be incorrect, as server might not have sent everything over. How do I check on the client, that the server did not do a graceful shutdown, but was some sort of crash?

Comment: Can you send the size of the transfer first?  That way the client can validate it got the right amount of bytes.  If it didn't, then something bad happened.

Comment: Yes, that can be done. I somehow feel there must be some other way the system can indicate. Isn't there any other way other than knowing the size before hand?

Comment: This question is to broad. 0 should not indicate EOF. Serverstate checks (like shutdown...) should not be part of a regular file transfer. How would you indicate a shutdown to the socket? Therefor you should use dedicated software/library. Look for SCADA.

Comment: thanks, i was more looking for something in C library or setsockoptions that can indicate that the peer process did not gracefully close the socket.

Comment: If the peer abruptly crashes you will *not* receive an EOF indication.

Comment: Well, currently I am getting 0 as the return from read, which is also returned when EOF or peer socket is closed gracefully.

Comment: @John that means the server end of the connection WAS closed gracefully (a `FIN` packet was sent). If the server software did not do that, the OS itself likely did. By default, closing a socket that has pending outbound data will try to send the data and close cleanly in the background. The server can [use `setsockopt(SO_LINGER)` to change that behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888429/), so that closing the socket without a preceding `shutdown()` will abort the connection immediately (`RST` is sent instead of `FIN`, causing `read()` to return -1) and any pending data is discarded

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did try the SO_LINGER option, set the timeout to 0, so that the close happens immediately. Now in the normal case where the server is gracefully doing a close, also returns a -1 on the client. The whole idea is to differentiate between graceful shutdown and crashes of the server on the client side read.

Comment: TCP is just a byte pipe, it knows nothing about files or other data constructs, neither does it know about applications. Therefore it only offers functionality that permits you to know if the connection was closed gracefully (FIN) or not (RST or timeout) by the _network stack_. A higher order protocol is needed to handle file transfers (i. e FTP, torrent or something you come up with).

Comment: @John are your calling `shutdown()` before calling `close()`? If not, you need to. A proper "graceful" close is to call `shutdown()` when you are done sending data to send a `FIN` to the peer, then `read()` until there is nothing left to receive (the peer's `FIN` is received, or an error) , and then finally `close()`. Make sure both peers do this same sequence. This way, with linger enabled with a 0 timeout, an abortive close on crash will make the peer's `read()` return -1, and a graceful close after transfer complete will make `read()` return 0.